# Adding <select> to HTML login form breaks. Why?

Tags: php, html

I have had a HTML login form working for a while but now I need to add `<select>` to it.

The problem is once I add it the login form breaks.

```
  <form action="" class="form-signin" method="post" role="form">
    <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Sign In</h2>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="user" id="user" placeholder="User" required autofocus>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="pass" id="pass" placeholder="Pass" required>
    <select class="form-control" id="site" name="site">  // This has been added
      <option value="Company A">Company A</option>
      <option value="Company B">Company B</option>
      <option value="Company C">Company C</option>
    </select> 
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
  </form>

  <?php
   $dbh = new PDO('sqlite:database.sqlite');

   $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE user = :user AND pass = :pass");

   foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
     $stmt->bindParam("$key", $_POST[$key]);
   }

   $stmt->execute();

   if ( $stmt->fetchColumn() > 0 ) {
     session_start();
     $_SESSION['active'] = 1;
     $_SESSION['site'] = $_POST['site']; // This has been added
     $_SESSION['user'] = $_POST['user'];
     header("Location: /");
   }
  ?>
```

I have marked the code that I have added with ``// This has been added`, so you can see what parts are breaking it but I don't understand why this would happen.

Comment: You really really really shouldn't store user's passwords as plain text.

Comment: when you say it doesnt work, does it give you an error? if you do die($_POST['site']); what do you get?

Answer (score 2):

cause of this line code

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE user = :user AND pass = :pass");
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
  $stmt->bindParam("$key", $_POST[$key]);
}
```

you are binding all post items but need only two `user` and `pass` so keep both to bind separate not in foreach like.

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE user = :user AND pass = :pass");
$stmt->bindParam(":user", $_POST['user']);
$stmt->bindParam(":pass", $_POST['pass']);
```

and if html is looking odd in select reason is(missing close option)
so replace

```
<option value="Company A">Company A<option>
```

to

```
<option value="Company A">Company A</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

change

```
  <option value="Company A">Company A<option>
```

to

```
  <option value="Company A">Company A</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not close the first option correctly.

```
<option value="Company A">Company A<option>
```

Should be :

```
<option value="Company A">Company A</option>
```

Comment: when I run the select without the closing tag the browser corrects it on render

Answer (score 0):

Change this please

```
<option value="Company A">Company A<option>
```

with

```
<option value="Company A">Company A</option>
```

Comment: Now you have 3 accurate solutions :)

Answer (score 0):

There's a typo in the first `option`: the closing tag is not a closing tag (missing slash).